# CakePHP HTTPsocket POST file upload

Tags: file, http, cakephp, post, upload

I have a CakePHP function which authorises an HTTP socket and then uses that socket to upload a file from a remote server. Everything works fine for some of the files on that server but several of them don't completely transfer.

I've looked at what's happening on Wireshark (although I understand very little) and it would appear that my server is sending an SSL alert 21 which I believe means it can't unencrypt the received data. It then starts sending reset requests to the remote server which are ignored.

The files download fine when I do it through a browser. I'm completely stuck now, it there anything else I can look at?

```
public function connect() {
  $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
  $zipFile = fopen(TMP . 'cif_schedule.gz', 'w');

  $postData = array('j_username' => 'my_username', 'j_password' => 'my_password');
  $authResponse = $httpSocket->post('https://login_url', $postData, array('redirect' => true));

  $httpSocket->setContentResource($zipFile);
  $fileResponse = $httpSocket->get('file_url', array(), array('redirect' => true));

  fclose($zipFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use PUT instead since Post is for passing data only. 
PUT is for files purposes.

```
http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-HttpSocket.html#_put
```